# Geometric question (middle line of a parallelogram)

Tags: geometric-construction

Let $ABCD$ be a parallelogram and $I,J$ are two points such that $AI = ID$ and $BJ = JD$. Show that ($IJ$) is parallel to ($AB$).

Comment: I think that you meant that I is the middle of the line segment with end points A and D and J is the middle of the line segment with end points B and D, no?

Comment: I agree with @user37238.  There have to be more constaints than you've given to be able to prove this.  As is, any points $I$ and $J$ that make isoceles triangles $\bigtriangleup AID$ and $\bigtriangleup BJD$ will satisfy the conditions, and it's easy to show a counterexample to the statement you're trying to prove.